# Correct application of eisenstein's criterion?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

I want to show that the polynomial $P(x,y,z) = z^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+3x^2z+3xz^2+3y^2z+3yz^2+6xyz$ is irreducible. I know that I can consider this as a polynomial in one variable z with coefficients in $\mathbb{k}[x, y]$, and I can apply Eisensteins with this in mind, but is it suitable to use $p=3$ here? If $\mathbb{k}= \mathbb{Q}$, is it not possible that given appropiate values of $x$ or $y$, Eisensteins would fail at $p=3$? If I cannot use $p=3$, what are my options?

Comment: Do you know the [generalized Eisenstein criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalized_criterion)? It's essentiallly the same as the usual critterion but over a general integral domain $D$ (here $D=k[x,y]$), and replacing a prime $p$ by a prime ideal. In this case you could take the ideal generated by $p$.

Comment: Thank you Javi!